# Limit of $I_p = \left(\int |f|^{h(p)}\right)^{\frac{p}{h(p)}}$ as $p \to \infty$

Tags: functional-analysis, limits

Let $f \in L^2 \backslash L^\infty$ on some bounded domain.  Let $h$ be a function such that $h(p) \to \frac 32$ as $p \to \infty$.

Consider $$I_p = \left(\int |f|^{h(p)}\right)^{\frac{p}{h(p)}}.$$

Is it true that $\lim_{p \to \infty} I_p \leq C$ exist for some finite constant $C$?

I don't think so, since there is a $p$ in the exponent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HInt: Try $x^{-1/4}$ on $(0,1).$

Answer (score 0):

you can simply choose h(p)=3/2, and any vector from L2 such that its norm larger than unity which obviously makes your integral diverge with respect to p.

The question must be: Does there exist an h(p) such that the integral is finite.